# Lenovo t400 laptop docking station with DVI out shows green artifacts when connected to monitor

Tags: windows-xp, video, lenovo-laptop, docking-station

I have a Lenovo T400 laptop, with Windows XP.  I have a docking station connected via DVI to my Samnsung monitor. I'm connected at 1920x1200 resolution and I keep seeing all these green dots (when colors are supposed to be near black).  It's really bad.    I have tried running on my Samsung monitor, at all sizes, even down town 1280x1024 like my monitors at work.

When I use the docking station at work, I am able to connect 2 1280x1024 NEC monitors (one via DVI, one through VGA, both through my docking station).   I have absolutely no issue there, both displays work great.

I have tried to update the drivers, I've even installed the latest video drivers from lenovo's site (DEC-02-2010).

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

Details:
Docking Station: Lenovo Advanced Mini Dock- 250410U - NIB
Montior at home: Samsung T240 24-inch monitor
Monitors at work: NEC monitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out was a bad cable on the KVM switch.  I just replaced it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it might be your Samsung T240 that has the problem- not your docking station. If your Samsung screen shows green artifacts when connected to other computers, the screen probably has dead pixels. Get a new screen if this is the case (or maybe, get the screen RMA'd).

Comment: I have it on a 4way KVM switch, it works on the other 4.  Turns out was a bad cable on the KVM switch